# Regex to find pattern and white space

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I want to find

```
//this is comment

//this is new comment
```

strings using regex.

My problem is, I do have following entries in the file:

```
/// this is valid comment
```

So here, I don't want to find and replace those valid comment but only which are
having any chars right after //

I am trying Visual Studio 2010 Find and Replace. So I also want regex for replace case.
that means, it should replace `//this is comment with` `// this is comment`. Here difference is the white space after `//`.

Comment: am wondering why you want to do this

Comment: @JayNanavati what is the expected result for `/// this is valid comment`?

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I want to find //This is comment and replace it with // This is comment. The replace part you gave replace it with // his is comment. which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:`//{[^ ]}`

Replace with:`// \1`

Comment: I gave it a try. Find works just fine. Now the replace does one wrong thing. It turns //This is comment to // his is comment. removing the char after //. can you help fix it?

Comment: if I do so, it replace like // $1his is comment.

Comment: Hi just to update you, I need to use //([^/ ]) as a find part and not //([^ ])

Answer (score 0):

```
s@//([^\s/])@// \1@
```

The first part matches `//` and any non-space character, which is captured.  The second part puts `//` and the captured part back in its place.

This assumes you don't have comments like `// comment //more comment`, although it should still work fine.

Comment: So what is Find part here and what is replacement part? I am to use it in Visual Studio 2010 Find & Replace.

Comment: Here I see s@//([^\s])@// also finds /// This is valid comment. It should not. It should only fine //and any chars right after //other than whitespace and /.

Comment: @JayNanavati I don't use visual studio, so I'm not positive.  The first `@` to `@` is find, after that is replace.  See updated answer